# HTML5 isometric canvas with viewport - very poor performance

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, kineticjs

I've modified `kinetic-viewport` library to make `scrollable` map but i'm experiencing performance-related problems. I've made `30x20` rectangles and they were rotated by `120*`. That's very simple as you can see but it lags much,I wonder what will happen if I put images on them and then make some sprites and animations? Game won't be playable I suppose.

What i'm doing wrong? I've never wrote a game before, commercial sites only. Maybe I should think differently while writing a game?

Demo - Scroll by pressing RMB. Use Mousewhell to zoom - http://godlike.hekko.pl/kinetic-viewport/demo.html

Source - http://godlike.hekko.pl/inne/kinetic-viewport.7z

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using setInterval: you'd better use the [requestAnimationFrame](http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/#requestAnimationFrame) API where available, since it's specifically thought for animations and will give you better framerate and less CPU usage (and, thus, less battery usage, if you're also targeting mobile devices).

If you're planning to create a scrolling game, you could as well try something specifically thought for games; I'd recommend [Canvace](http://canvace.com/), which I'm also involved in. :)

Comment: I bought book about html5 canvas and rewrote the code using requestAnimationFrame and some features. I removed kineticJS too because it was too heavy.